# Graphs with zero eigenvalues

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I search about known graphs have spectrum with the most zero eigenvalues respect to  their adjacency matrix. I know null, complete, bipartite and cocktel party graphs. 
 Any kind of suggestion is appreciated. Thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: In the category of "highest multiplicity of zero as an eigenvalue", it's rather hard to beat the zero matrix, coming from the null graph. Is that really the question you mean to ask?

Comment: @Jmerry,Thank you for your conment but I search in family of known graphs. I don't want to construct graphs with this property.

Comment: If you don't want people to propose graphs you haven't listed, but also don't want people to propose the graphs you have listed, then it is unclear what it is you do want. If there is some specific list of graphs you consider "known" then provide that list.

Answer (score 1):

Take the bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$, then its spectrum is 
$$ \{ \sqrt{mn}, 0^{m+n-2}, - \sqrt{mn}\}$$

Surely one of the most non-trivial graph with the desired property.
Otherwise yes as stated in the comments, take the null matrix.

**Edit** you should take a look at [this article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/03081087.2016.1162133?scroll=top&needAccess=true), talking about cospectrality of complete bipartite graph. You should be able to construct graph with spectrum close to the complete bipartite's one, hence with some null values

**Edit 2** Looking at [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X1100327X), you can generalize on complete multi partite graphs, with $k$ sets and eigenvalue $0^{n-k}$. After that i don't know if you can do much better.

Comment: Sorryy, answered before the edit "no bipartite"

Comment: @ Thomas Thank you for your conment but I pointed the bipartite graphs in my question. I search in family of known graphs. I don't want to construct graphs with this property.